# How Spring AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer threads recognises messages in Active MQ queue as not duplicate

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

In my current architecture Spring **AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer** threads which polls message from ActiveMQ queue dispatches messages from queue towards remote server.

Now my question is how it recognises that the message which it is going to dispatch from queue is already dispatched by it or not?

Assume remote server is slow in sending back response to the same AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer thread and so AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer thread is still waiting for response and so could not delete message from queue and copy of that message is still in ActiveMQ queue.

Now assume 100 messages are present in queue out of that 1 message is still not deleted from queue due to slow receiver and 99 messages are already deleted. Now another AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer thread which keeps pooling message from ActiveMQ queue will find out this message and in that will it again dispatch this message or it will not since it recognizes that this message is already dispatched once. 
If it recognizes it as already dispatched then please explain how it recognizes?

Thanks and Regards,

Prakash Chandra

Answer (score 1):

That's just part of the JMS specification. When a message is delivered to a consumer from a queue, the broker will not deliver it to another consumer. The message is actually removed from the broker when the consumer acknowledges delivery (usually after completing processing).

If the original consumer crashes, the broker detects it and automatically re-queues the message for re-delivery. Similarly if the consumer is transactional and rolls back the message, it is re-queued.

Read the JMS specification.